# OnPlatform in NavigationPage using XAML

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform

Given this original code, I'm trying to hide the icon on Android:

```
<NavigationPage Title="Page" Icon="page_icon.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <views:MyPage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```

I have attempted to use OnPlatform many different ways and cannot get it to work. Here are some things I have tried:

```
<NavigationPage Title="Page">          
    <NavigationPage.Icon>     
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">     
            <OnPlatform.iOS>page_icon.png</OnPlatform.iOS> 
            <OnPlatform.Android>{x:Null}</OnPlatform.Android>    
        </OnPlatform>    
    </NavigationPage.Icon>     
    <x:Arguments>
        <views:MyPage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```

This produced the error:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

I also tried this:

```
<NavigationPage Title="Rater">
    <OnPlatform 
        x:Key="Icon"
        x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
        iOS="tab_feed.png"
        Android="{x:Null}"
    />
    <x:Arguments>
        <views:MyPage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```

Which runs, *but no icons show up on iOS*.

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your questions, nor add [solved] devices into titles. Instead, click on the "Answer Your Question" button and add an answer that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you deal with icons, it may be a separate question but OnPlatform was redesigned. Here is how you suppose to use it now:

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="SwitchOnColor"  x:TypeArguments="Color" >
    <On Platform="iOS,Android" >#0000FF</On>
    <On Platform="UWP">#FF0000</On>
</OnPlatform>
```

Comment: Thank you. Tweaking your example a bit I got it to work. I will modify my question with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

With the help of Yuri S's example, I was able for create markup that worked as intended on iOS and Android. This is it.

```
    <NavigationPage.Icon>
        <OnPlatform x:Key="SwitchOnIcon" x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
            <On Platform="iOS">tab_feed.png</On>
        </OnPlatform>
    </NavigationPage.Icon>
```